# Data clustering and comparison between two arrays

Tags: c++, mysql, arrays, sorting, hashtable

I have **two collections** of elements. How can I pick out those with duplicates and put them into each group with least amount of comparison? Preferably in C++.

For Example given

> Array 1 = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 8, …}
>
> Array 2 = {2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 7, 7, 8, 8, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, …}.

At first, I want to cluster data.

> Array 1 = { Group 1 = {1, 1, 1, 1, …},  Group 2 = {2, 2, 2, 2, …},  Group 3 = {3, …},  Group 4 = {4, 4, …}, Group 5 = {5, 5, 5, …},  Group 6 = {8, …} }.
>
> Array 2 = { Group 1 = {1, 1, …},  Group 2 = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2 …}, Group 3 = {4, 4 ,4, …}, Group 4 = {7, 7, …}, Group 5 = {8, 8, 8 …} }.

And second, I want data matching.

> Group 1 of Array 1 == Group 1 of Array 2
>
> Group 2 of Array 1 == Group 2 of Array 2
>
> Group 4 of Array 1 == Group 3 of Array 2
>
> Group 6 of Array 1 == Group 5 of Array 2

How can I solve this problem in C++? Please give me your brilliant tips.

---

Additionally, I will explain my problem in detail. I have two data sets which is calculated in stereo image. Array 1 is data of left camera, and Array 2 is data of right camera. My final goal is to match groups which have same values such as group 6 of array1 and group 5 of array 2. Data ordering is not my consideration. I just want to find same values between groups in two arrays. (Will you recommend me to use data ordering first to reduce the number of comparison? ).

In order to solve this problem, should I use ‘std::map’ for data clustering, and compare those N! times (N: no. of groups in array 1 or 2)? Is this best way that I can do?

I’d like to get your advice. Thank you for sharing my problems.

---

### My conclusion

My approach is to use map container in C++ STL.

1. Make 2 map containers (Array1_map, Array2_map).
2. Insert value of each array into the map containers as a key, and insert index of each array into the map as a value. (Two data of both arrays are orderly saved in a map without duplication.)
3. Use find() member function of map container for data matching.
4. After data matching, I was able to get the indexes of each array which have the matched keys (corresponding keys).

Thank you for all your helpful answers!

Comment: _"Please give me your brilliant tips."_ We don't do such thing here.

Comment: you want two histograms and compare each bin?

Comment: histograms are easy with `std::map`

Comment: do the number sets have a min and max range, or will the elements be of arbitrary size?

Comment: The number sets have a limited range. The range was related to the camera resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can see to do this is to construct a histogram of each array.  Then you can compare those histograms together.  That should be O(NlogN) to convert each array to a histogram where N is the array size and then O(N) to compare the histograms when `N` is the number of unique elements in the array (size of the map).  That would look like

```
int arr1[] = {...};
int arr2[] = {...};
std::map<int, int> arr1_histogram, arr2_histogram;
for (auto e : arr1)
    arr1_histogram[e]++;
for (auto e : arr2)
    arr2_histogram[e]++;

if (arr1_histogram == arr2_histogram)
    // true case
else
    // false case
```